# Wordpress - Portfolio and website

Tags: wordpress

I am developing my portfolio website in WordPress and I am trying to have both thumbnails for my project in the main page and a blog.

I have gone through the documentation and different examples and I was wondering if there is a way to have both the projects output and the blog without using the wp_query for the project thumbnails while having the posts only for the blog and without using a plugin to output the projects.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed I figured it out after asking around and reading some stuff. There are two options for people who want to build their portfolio and also want to have a blog inside their portfolio.

There are two options:

1. Having a wordpress within a wordpress. So basically in my portfolio I could have a link that takes me to a different wordpress and just manage them as multisites from the same dashborad. [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).
2. Create a query of posts that use categories for the projects that you want to show. So basically in posts, create a category called projects: By using a [query request](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).